# Install failed when install my unmanaged packaged

Tags: custom-object, publisher, global-actions, unmanaged-package

im facing issue on installing my customn unmanaged packaged app in my another dev org. here is the failed message

**Your requested install failed. Please try this again.**

**None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization should have been affected by this error.
If this error persists, contact salesforce.com Support through your normal channels and reference number: 15252823-25109 (1373252180)**

i have publisher action on my Custom object, action just create the new record.
when i remove the publisher action and repackage my app. then the app successfully install to my another dev org.
how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact SalesForce and quote them the reference number **15252823-25109 (1373252180)**. They will then be able to tell you the exact error that is causing the install to fail.